# Samsung s7 is on dead mode, buttons are also not working, usb debugging is also off.. Please help me to recover my phone

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-s7

my phone is Samsung Galaxy S7. Suddenly while using the phone, it stuck on black screen with lights on both navigation n back button.  Then after 1-2 minutes,  it stuck on restart on loop mode. After few minutes the screen again got black with blue led notification light on & no button was working till whole night it was like this. Then in morning, the led light turned off automatically but the phone condition was same, black screen with no button working. Even when i connected charger then also charging red light was not on. It wasn't charging at all.

USB debugging is also off on my phone so couldn't connect it to the computer to fix it.

Please help me to recover my phone or to let me know how tk turn on debugging when phone & buttons are not working.

Comment: https://youtu.be/qfSJmwUGATA